# how to split a table into two in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, compression

I have a table of size 6 TB which grows around 20 GB per day. I have tried the OLTP compression and secureFile compression but it gives compression ratio around 20% only.

So I want to split the table by moving the LOB column to new table in which I will be using secureFIle LOB compression & de-duplication features.   After removing LOB from original table may give a better OLTP compression ratio.

Please suggest the best possible method for spiting the table considering size of table.

Note: The table has partitions created per day bases.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going to split this because it **might** give better compression? Why not test it first and be certain? I'd create the new tables(s) in a different tablespace, copy some data (perhaps a few days worth) into the new tables, and determine if there's any benefit to doing this. Best of luck.

Comment: Seems that you've missed to add another vital piece of info: you statement that you get 20gb of data per day missing the CONTEXT: how many records in average those 20gb of data? Oracle 10g and below can have in LOB 4GB; Oracle 11g can have 128TB !!! (according to the docs - i personally did not check such)    http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT513   ;    http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm (search for paragraph "Large Object (LOB) Datatypes"

Answer (score 1):

What is the usage profile of your table?

Frequently a table with data coming in like this ...

> "The table has partitions created per day bases."

... has  high demand for the recent records and lower demand for the older records.  In particular it is common for DML (updates, inserts and deletes) to focus on the newer stuff, and for the older records to be fixed.

If that is your use case you can apply stronger compression to the older records, such as `COMPRESS FOR QUERY` or even `COMPRESS FOR ARCHIVE`.  These commands can be applied to individual  partitions, using `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER PARTITION ... COMPRESS ...` .  [Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tables.htm#ADMIN11630)

You will get much greater space gains from FOR QUERY and especially FOR ARCHIVE compression than splitting the table and sticking with FOR OLTP.  The price for that is much more expensive DML.  So really only use them on data which is definitely locked.  If your data management is well organized and you have spread partitions across multiple tablespaces you can make the pertinent tablespaces READ ONLY.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tspaces.htm#ADMIN11378).